# How to show thumbnail and preview of video in react-native-camera?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

How to show thumbnail and preview of video in react-native-camera? Which means able to play it back before submitting.

Comment: Trying the same help me out with this --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280005/react-native-camera-video-capture-unable-to-preview-and-upload-as-snapchat-vide